# How do I enable client side validation in IdentityCore for sign up

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` for mange login logout functionalities. I have following class for signup process. As you can see, i have used some validation attributes. I want them to work not only in the server side, but also in the client side.

```
    public class SignupUserModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Full name is required")]
        [DisplayName("Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [Compare("ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "Password Not Match")]
        //[RegularExpression(@"/[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/? ~]/", ErrorMessage = "Required an non-alphanumeric character")]
        [MinLength(5)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm your password")]
        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Note that i have already installed **Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch** for client side validation.
And also include following script file in the bottom of my razor view.(Although both of them done the same job, i tried using both of them)

```
 @section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml" />
    }
}
```

Also note that all client side validations are working fine in other part of the applications. This happens only in the signup page. On my pov, i think i am missing something with *identity core* package. Anyone have an idea? I really appreciate your comment.

Comment: You need to validate in Controller side for Model validations

Comment: Can you provide me any reference link or example for that??

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Follow above link you may get clarity Regarding that

Comment: You can add a post method to your controller and use the `SignupUserModel` to receive parameters for validation.This way you will have the validation attribute added in the model and you can continue to add the rest of the validations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the original question is properly answered. All the answers posted are for server side validations. I face the same issue as the original post. I can only perform server side validation for new user sign ups and it is a bother because my new user registration form is done on a modal. Going back to the controller and returning the view does not trigger the modal automatically.